# Ansible "win_lineinfile" two changes to make on lines where originals are identical

Tags: json, regex, ansible

We have a third party product that we deploy using Ansible.  We use the "win_lineinfile" module to make necessary configuration changes to suit our environments.

My issue is there are two lines in a config file exactly the same ("EntityId"), and they need to have different config put into them.  This is the section of file how we receive it, that needs transforming;

```
        "ServiceProviderOptions": {
            "EntityId": "http://localhost:50000/saml"
        },
        "IdentityProviderOptions": {
            "EntityId": "",
            "SingleSignOnEndpoint": {
                "url": ""
            },
```

This needs to look like this (obfuscated out our business sensitive text!);

```
 "ServiceProviderOptions": {
    "EntityId": "https://our_application_server/saml"
  },
  "IdentityProviderOptions": {
    "EntityId": "http://our_adfs_server/services/trust",
    "SingleSignOnEndpoint": {
      "url": "https://our_adfs_server/"
    },
```

What I actually end up with is this;

```
 "ServiceProviderOptions": {
    "EntityId": "http://localhost:50000/saml"
  },
  "IdentityProviderOptions": {
    "EntityId": "http://our_adfs_server/services/trust",
    "EntityId": "https://our_application_server/saml"
    "SingleSignOnEndpoint": {
      "url": "https://our_adfs_server/"
    },
```

So rather than amending the first line, it has dropped both lines under the second location, and I have no idea why!!  I have tried to use a combination of "insertafter" with "regexp" to try to define what I want where, but it simply isn't working how I intend.

Here is the section of my code dealing with this;

```
- name: Alter lines without unique keys (use insertafter)
  win_lineinfile:
    path: C:\{{ item.file }}
    insertafter: "{{ item.beforeLine }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regExp }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
  with_items:    
    - { file: 'config_file.json', beforeLine: 'ServiceProviderOptions', regExp: 'EntityId.*', line: '{{ ServiceProviderEntityId }}' }
    - { file: 'config_file.json', beforeLine: 'IdentityProviderOptions', regExp: 'EntityId.*,', line: '{{ IdentityProviderEntityId }}' }
```

Again, with the juicy bits taken out that could get me sacked!

If anyone has any suggestions how I should go about this, I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realised, it's only a matter of time before someone says, just transform on the strength of "http://localhost:50000/saml" being in the first line to change, but it's inconsistent.  The only consistent bit is the "EntityId".

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has stumbled on this and is looking for an answer to the same!

I have got round this issue by removing the lines first and then adding them back in again using the "insertafter" argument in the "win_lineinfile" module.

role/vars/mail.yml -

```
MyVarArray:
  - { file: 'path\file.json', beforeLine: 'ServiceProviderOptions', regExp: 'EntityId.*', line: '{{ Line_to_go_under_SvcPrvdOpts }}' }
  - { file: 'path\file.json', beforeLine: 'IdentityProviderOptions', regExp: 'EntityId.*,', line: '{{ Line_to_go_under_IdtyPrvdOpts }}' }
```

role/tasks/mail.yml -

```
 - name: Remove non-unique lines ready to be recreated
   win_lineinfile:
     path: C:\{{ item.file }}
     regexp: "{{ item.regExp }}"
     state: absent
   with_items: "{{ MyVarArray }}"
 
 - name: Alter lines without unique keys (use insertafter)
   win_lineinfile:
     path: C:\{{ item.file }}
     insertafter: "{{ item.beforeLine }}"
     line: "{{ item.line }}"
   with_items: "{{ MyVarArray }}"
```

This works, and maybe proves a point that it's not worth trying to be too clever all of the time!  Especially with automation, sometimes it's worth taking things one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in your code. Please also refer to the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_lineinfile_module.html).

a) The correct parameter is `regex` not `regexp`. You should use one that will match if the value is unset, but will not match if the value is set. Like that it will only be changed if necessary.
b) At `insertafter` you probably need to supply a regex that matches the line. E.g. `.*ServiceProviderOptions.*$`.

I could not try this, as I don't have a windows at hand. You might need to tweak the regexes. [Documentation for .NET regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Thanks for replying
I checked and it says "regexp" in anisible-doc. Thought that odd, I'd have just expected a big red error if I'd got a key word wrong.
Being specific with the "line above" had no any affect either.  To my understanding, you only have to specify text that is unique in the file rather than the whole line; that's how I use it elsewhere, and it seems to work.
Maybe I'm just asking too much of the module?! Maybe the solution is to delete the lines with "EntityId" in them and then just add the whole line in with an "insertafter".  Unless anyone has a cleaner solution?

Comment: This is really weird, [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regex) it says *regex* but everywhere else, it says *regexp*.

Comment: It also says "aliases: regexp"